# Segmentation fault simple nasm program

Tags: assembly, nasm

I just started learning linux 64bit assembly and was trying to really understand the differences between lea and mov.
But when creating a test file I get a segmentation fault of which I just do not understand why. The fault arises with the `mov r10,[rax]` in the sample code. But when I change the place of `mov r10,[rax]` with `lea r11,[rax]` I get the fault when the lea is executed.

My program:

```
global _start
section .text

_start:
mov rax,16
lea r11,[rax]
mov r10,[rax]
mov r9,rax

mov rax,60
xor edi,edi
syscall
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect at the memory location 16(0x10)?

Your code is

```
mov rax,16
mov r10,[rax]
```

which means that you try to load the 64bit value from memory address `RAX` into `R10`. The address 16 is normally not mapped into your program space.

Comment: I think I am slowly getting it yes. So it is trying to see what is at the memory location of 16 so trying to read memory at 0x16 which the program is not allowed to do?

Comment: @Wealot: Basically that's it. You try to read memory location 16 (0x10) and you're not allowed to.